# Dividing worksheet values

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to divide by worksheet values and place within a variable h. My worksheet is ws and is set. Here is the code:

```
h = (ws.Range("O" & y).Value2 - ws.Range("S" & y).Value2) / ws.Range("S" & y).Value2
```

The problem seems to be with `ws.Range("S" & y).value2`. What's strange is when i substract `S` from `O` I return a value. It's only when I divide that get all 0s returned - which is not expected. Is there something unique about division or perhaps something to do with my data on worksheet?

Comment: Could you provide come test values?

Comment: What are the inputs and do you have a `Dim h as ...` statement anywhere?

Comment: O = 32650 and S = 36731

Comment: I will bet you have h declare as Long or Integer as @MattCremeens stated.  You need to declare it as a Double.

Comment: You are getting that error because you have declared `h` as Integer or a `Long`. Declare it as `Double` The division comes to `-0.111105061120035`

Comment: Yes. I've tried Dim h as integer and Dim h as long

Comment: Ah. Ok, I get it. So integer and long can only be whole numbers?

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/programming/visual-basic/standard-vba-data-types/

Comment: Thanks much. It's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim y As Long, h As Double, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    y = 3
    h = (ws.Range("O" & y).Value2 - ws.Range("S" & y).Value2) / ws.Range("S" & y).Value2
    MsgBox h
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Why a `Variant`? Using variants is slower than using the other fundamental data types. Use `Variants` only when you are not sure.

Comment: yeah, I saw it :)